# Have COVID-19 vaccination trials started in Seattle?

Tags: medical-science, medications, vaccines, covid-19

I am reading conflicting information on this.

In a supposed **Associated Press Exclusive**, [a report went out March 16th](https://apnews.com/76b614811eef32955180c8260188bc24) saying:

> U.S. researchers gave the first shots in a first test of an experimental coronavirus vaccine Monday, leading off a worldwide hunt for protection even as the pandemic surges.
>
> With careful jabs in the arms of four healthy volunteers, scientists at the Kaiser Permanente Washington Research Institute in Seattle began an anxiously awaited first-stage study of a potential COVID-19 vaccine

This came to my attention as [BBC News reported a day after](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-51906604), that US volunteers are testing the first vaccine.

> Four patients received the jab at the Kaiser Permanente research facility in Seattle, Washington, reports the Associated Press news agency.

Yet, [Time says](https://time.com/5790545/first-covid-19-vaccine/) (emphasis mine):

> The first vials were sent to the National Institute of Allergy and Infectious Diseases (NIAID), part of the National Institutes of Health (NIH) in Bethesda, MD, **which will ready the vaccine for human testing as early as April**.

They also mention testing [a drug called remdesivir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remdesivir) that had been developed for Ebola, on a patient infected with the virus.

> Volunteers will be randomly assigned to receive either the drug or a placebo intravenously for 10 days, and they will have blood tests and nose and throat swabs taken every two days to track the amount of virus in their bodies.

The reason for trialling remdesivir is because:

> Remdesivir showed encouraging results among animals infected with two related coronaviruses, one responsible for severe acute respiratory syndrome (SARS) and another for causing Middle East respiratory syndrome (MERS).

Gilead - the developers of the drug - [have reported of phase 3 testing](https://www.gilead.com/news-and-press/press-room/press-releases/2020/2/gilead-sciences-initiates-two-phase-3-studies-of-investigational-antiviral-remdesivir-for-the-treatment-of-covid-19) of remdesivir on approximately 1000 patients.

So has vaccination trials started in a separate research lab in Seattle, or is this another misinformation report by the press?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of these claims and people in the office I work with are repeating them. Would love to see a good answer to this. I don't know somebody downvoted... I upvoted.

Comment: Is this questions limited to the US? The quotes seem to all be about the US, but there's no country tag on the question presently. The question is also rather unclear as to what it is skeptical about. That any trials are being conducted (in the US)? The final question in the body seems to be about a particular trial in Seattle, or something like that.

Comment: I took the two stories as the start of human testing for two different vaccines.  Both stories had video and sound byte from a person receiving vaccination.

Comment: @Fizz - You made a valid point and so I edited to suit

Answer (score 8):

I decided to go and look on the website for the research institute in Seattle and they confirm that [testing is indeed underway](https://www.kpwashingtonresearch.org/news-and-events/recent-news/news-2020/kaiser-permanente-launches-coronavirus-vaccine-study-seattle).

> On March 16, 2020, Kaiser Permanente Washington Health Research Institute (KPWHRI) gave the first-ever injection of an investigational vaccine for the 2019 novel coronavirus, SARS-CoV-2, to 4 volunteers participating in a [phase I federally sponsored clinical trial](https://corona.kpwashingtonresearch.org/).
>
> To date, no other trial has been launched in people of any vaccine for this virus, which causes COVID-19.

The National Institute of Allergy and Infectious Diseases (NIAID) who were mentioned in the TIME report as receiving the vaccine selected KPWHRI to conduct the trial.

Comment: Plus https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/nih-clinical-trial-investigational-vaccine-covid-19-begins

Comment: and https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04283461?term=mrna-1273&draw=2&rank=1